# Extract specific values from stdClass Object

Tags: arrays, object, stdclass

**I have the following stdClass Object contained within $response:**

```
stdClass Object ( [domain] => stdClass Object ( [id] => d1111111 [spamscore] => 75 [rejectscore] => 200 ) [domainalias] => Array ( ) [wildcard] => Array ( ) [catchall] => Array ( ) [forward] => Array ( ) [mailbox] => Array ( 

[0] => stdClass Object ( [highEmailNotification] => [id] => m1111111 [lastPasswordChange] => 2020-02-19T22:41:12+00:00 [local] => mailbox1 [lowEmailNotification] => [quotaMB] => 10240 [receive] => 1 [rejectscore] => [send] => 1 [spamscore] => [usageMB] => 0 [enabled] => 1 )

[1] => stdClass Object ( [highEmailNotification] => [id] => m2222222 [lastPasswordChange] => 2020-02-17T15:46:21+00:00 [local] => mailbox2 [lowEmailNotification] => [quotaMB] => 10240 [receive] => 1 [rejectscore] => [send] => 1 [spamscore] => [usageMB] => 0 [enabled] => 1 )

[2] => stdClass Object ( [highEmailNotification] => [id] => m3333333 [lastPasswordChange] => 2020-02-19T15:00:36+00:00 [local] => mailbox3 [lowEmailNotification] => [quotaMB] => 1024 [receive] => 1 [rejectscore] => 0 [send] => 1 [spamscore] => 75 [usageMB] => 0 [enabled] => 1 ) ) [spamblacklist] => Array ( ) [spamwhitelist] => Array ( ) [responder] => Array ( ) [name] => domain.com )
```

I need to convert it into an array and extract particular values, i.e. [id] and [local] from it.

**Speed is also an issue, as this array will grow to thousands of items, so if there is other, quicker way than 'foreach' it would be better.**

I used some suggestions from here, such as:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response), True);

foreach ($array as $var)
{
    echo $var['id'] . ' - ' . $var['local'] . "<br>";
}
```

and got partial success with the results:

### d1111111 -

### -

### -

### -

-
i - i

(so it found the very first [id] value)

it however missed the most important values I am after.

**What I need to get is:**

m1111111 - mailbox1

m2222222 - mailbox2

m3333333 - mailbox3

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The values you're trying to print is in a nested array within `$response`.

Try this.

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response['mailbox']), True);

foreach ($array as $var)
{
    echo $var['id'] . ' - ' . $var['local'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: That doesn't bring any results at all.